# Sending JMS Message to WMB with specified encoding

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'am trying to send message to WMB specifying encoding = 273, but it only changes encoding in Properties and MQRFH2, but not in MQMD (it's 546 there). What am I doing wrong?

```
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

private static final String SETTINGS_QUEUE = "REQUESTS/INTERNAL/GETSETTINGS";

public void sendSettingsMessage(String componentName, String componentVersion) {
    try {
        MQTopic topic = new MQTopic(SETTINGS_QUEUE);
        topic.setMQMDWriteEnabled(true);
        topic.setEncoding(WMQConstants.WMQ_ENCODING_NATIVE);
        jmsTemplate.send(topic, session -> {
            Message message = session.createMessage();
            message.setStringProperty("resource", "/settings/" + componentName + "." + componentVersion);
            message.setStringProperty("method", "GET");
            message.setStringProperty("source", "UI");
            message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_ENCODING, WMQConstants.WMQ_ENCODING_NATIVE);
            message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_ENCODING, WMQConstants.WMQ_ENCODING_NATIVE);
            return message;
        });
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The CCSID given by the MQMD can be overwritten by the CCSID in the RFH2, and the WMB flow should be aware of this, so it would parse your data with the CCSID in the RFH2. So I don't see why you need to set the CCSID in the MQMD.

Comment: I need the same encoding in MQMD и MQRFH2 because this difference affects the creation of segmented message in WMB. My current solution is to set the same encoding as in MQMD in Properties and MQRFH2 headers - 546 by:

message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_ENCODING, CMQC.MQENC_REVERSED);